# Trying to send bytes over USB

Tags: python, usb, microchip

I have downloaded Python 3.5, am using PyCharm, have downloaded a library for my bridge chip, MCP2210, am trying to communicate over USB after successfully communicating over the utility and terminal softwares that come with the chip.  I found an instruction about using USB, copied:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
```

tried to run, got an error message about Module not found: No module named 'usb'.  What am I doing wrong?
Have I neglected to first download something?

Comment: Python 3.5 is relatively old (released in September 2015); the most recent version is 3.8.

Comment: It seems likely that you haven't installed [`pyusb`](https://github.com/walac/pyusb), despite that code requiring it.

Comment: As hinted above, many packages are not included in a standard Python installation so you have to install them yourself. This is often done using `pip`, but there may also be packages available from your Linux distribution. On a side note, I found at least one dedicated Python library for your specific purpose for example: https://github.com/arachnidlabs/mcp2210. I am not saying that you should use this instead of the more generic USB library though, because I haven't evaluated it, but it's good to be aware of the solutions that exist before trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Does this library include instructions on how to update your python installation? Check out [Install, uninstall, and upgrade packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) in the PyCharm docs.

Comment: _got an error message_ Please provide the entire error message, as well as some more information on your environment.

Comment: running under Windows 7, Python 3.5, library for MCP2210 downloaded, copied from https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst:  import usb.core
import usb.util
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x04D8, idProduct=0x00DE)
if dev is None:
RESULT:   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Stereotaxic/begin.py", line 1, in <module>
    import usb.core
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usb'

Process finished with exit code 1